# dragable div outside iframe in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a div mydiv which is dragable and it is placed inside abc.ascx page and this abc.ascx page is displayed in some other pqr.aspx page(parent page) using iframe.

I am able to drag mydiv only within abc.ascx but i want to drag mydiv in full window.

i have tried somthing like this but it is not working.

```
    $("#mydiv").each(function () {
         $(this).draggable({
             containment: $(this).parent().parent()
     })
 });
```

the div is not dragable outside iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't possible do drag an element outside of his frame, instead of the iframe you could use a div which loads the "abc.aspx":

```
$("#iframediv).load("path/to/abc.aspx");
```